# apache nutch does not add sublinks to main site

Tags: database, web-crawler, nutch

Could anyone please give a guidence on how to properly configure apache nutch in order to get some amount of records in the database as a result of crawling a web site. I would very appreciate that!

Here details:

I've got the following line in my `bin/urls/seed.txt` file:

```
http://transmetod.ru/
```

The following is the line from regex-urlfilter.txt file (all other regexps are commented) :

```
+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*transmetod.ru/([a-z0-9]*\.)*
```

Basically I expect lots of records in the database to appear as a result of crawling, but the only thing a got there is just a single record with base url ( with out any other records with additional sublinks in the url )

This is a command line I use to run *apache-nutch-2.1* project:

```
./nutch crawl urls -depth 3 -topN 10000
```

Can anyone point me out to mistake I've made or gust give some piece of advice ?

P.S.: basically, when I built project and ran it without any changes, I didn't get a bunch of records as well... (if I remmember things right)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you regex filter to:

```
+^http://([a-z0-9]*.)transmetod.ru/
```

Also, when you first run Nutch, it will crawl the urls you put in your seed file.
The next time your run the crawl, using the same crawl folder, It should pick up the outlinks of the first page and crawl them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, 'll try and 'll get the feedback about whether it helped or not !